# Где ошибка в компараторе?

Tags: c++, map, шахматы

Для развлечения набрасывал задачку о расстановке N ферзей, путем перебора всех перестановок. Все получается отлично, нужные 92 перестановки для обычной доски получаются.

Захотел получить группы перестановок - ну, сколько принципиально разных перестановок, которые не получаются симметриями или поворотами. Для этого добавляю `map` и компаратор, который сравнивает векторы и, если один можно получить из другого, говорит при сравнении `false`. Пересматривал на тестовых примерах — вроде бы работает верно. Но в `map` оказываются перестановки, которые получаются путем симметрий - говорит, что всего 46 групп. Что явно неверно - должно быть 12!

Никак не могу увидеть свою ошибку, может, кто поможет понять, где именно я поступаю неверно? Проблема в компораторе или нет?

Вот код, он небольшой:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

// Создание всех возможных расстановок с помощью симметрий
vector<vector<int>> makeV(const vector<int>& a) {
    const size_t N = a.size();
    vector<vector<int>> p(7, vector<int>(N));

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
        p[0][i]            = int(N - 1 - a[i]); // H
        p[1][N - 1 - i]    = int(a[i]);         // V
        p[2][N - 1 - i]    = int(N - 1 - a[i]); // O
        p[3][a[i]]         = int(i);            // \s
        p[4][a[i]]         = int(N - 1 - i);    // ->
        p[5][N - 1 - a[i]] = int(i);            // <-
        p[6][N - 1 - a[i]] = int(N - 1 - i);    // /s
        }
    return p;
    }

// Класс для сравнения двух векторов (можно ли получить один
// из второго симметриями - тогда равны)
struct lessVec {

    bool operator()(const vector<int>& a, const vector<int>& b) const {
        if (a == b) return false;

        vector<vector<int>> p = makeV(a);

        // Если получается хоть одной симметрией - равны, вернуть false
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) if (b == p[i]) return false;

        // Обычное сравнение
        return a < b;
        }
    };

// true, если есть пара бьющих ферзей
bool fight(const vector<int>& p) {
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < p.size() - 1; ++i) {
        for (unsigned int j = i + 1; j < p.size(); ++j) {
            if (int(j - i) == abs(p[j] - p[i])) return true;
            }
        }

    return false;
    }

// Решение для доски NxN
pair<int, int> solve(int N) {
    map<vector<int>, int, lessVec> m; // Сбор групп решений
    // Проверяю все перестановки
    vector<int> p(N);

    for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) p[i] = i;

    int count = 0;  // Количество решений

    do {
        if (!fight(p)) {
            ++count;
            m[p]++;    // Сколько в группе решений
            }
        } while (next_permutation(p.begin(), p.end()));

    return make_pair(count, int(m.size()));
    }

int main() {
    for (int i = 8; i <= 8; ++i) {
        auto p = solve(i);
        cout << setw(2) << i << "  "
             << setw(7) << p.first << "  "
             << setw(7) << p.second << endl;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

У вас ошибка в компараторе. Например, можно придумать четыре различные позиции `a`, `b`, `c`, `d` для которых `a = b`, `c = d`, `a < c`, `d < b`. Откуда можно вывести что `a < a`.

Правильный компаратор может быть устроен так:

```python
def less(a, b):
    p_min = min(makeV(a))
    q_min = min(makeV(b))
    return p_min < q_min
```

Введем отношение эквивалентности. Две позиции эквивалентны, если одну в другую можно перевести поворотами и отражениями. Все позиции можно сгруппировать в классы эквивалентности. В каждом классе выделим канонического представителя. В дальнейшем, когда нам понадобится сравнить два элемента, мы будем сравнивать их канонических представителей.

Способ выбора канонического представителя не важен. Важно лишь что две эквивалентные позиции имеют одного и того же канонического представителя, а две неэквивалентные - разных. Например, можно выбрать минимальную в обычном смысле позицию в классе.

Так как каждый элемент имеет канонического преставителя и так как на канонических преставителях порядок отвечает всем требуемым свойствам (транзитивность, антирефлексивность, асимметричность), то и новый порядок тоже задан корректно.

Comment: Большое спасибо! жаль, что плюсик можно поставить только один)) О такой возможности, как вы описали, даже не подумал...